# How make radio buttons in swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3

I am creating a Swift iOS app in which I have to show a Radio Buttons which accepts Horizontal and Vertical ways. I have found one library at GitHub which looks the solution of my problem but it's show only Horizontal way direction(side by side direction), I need vertical ways(i.e Display one radio button after below another radio button) . Any guidance will be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Link : https://github.com/sag333ar/SKRadioButton

Comment: You can create an array of UIButton with an image for `selected` state. Once a user selects one of them - go through the array in order to deselect other buttons. Btw, for iOS a UISegmentedControl usually using as radio buttons.

Comment: You can see this link - https://github.com/shamasshahid/SSRadioButtonsController

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is less code solution I believe!

```
@IBOutlet weak var btn1: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var btn2: UIButton!
.
.
.
.
@IBOutlet weak var btn10: UIButton!


var arrButtons:[UIButton] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        arrButtons.append(btn1)
        arrButtons.append(btn2)
        //so, on
    }
```

Go to button property and set state Config property selected image for UIButton so, it will replace image when isSelected property is true.

Also Bind touchUpInside event to every buttons with "btnRadioPrressed" method.

```
    @IBAction func btnRadioPrressed(sender: UIButton) {

        for btn in arrButons {
            btn.isSelected = false
        }
        if let index = arrButons.index(where: { $0 == sender }) {
            arrButons[index].isSelected = true
        }
    }
```

Hope this will help you with less code.

Answer (score 0):

The link you share already can make vertical buttons , in usage   it describes using it inside a horizontal `UIStackView`

Comment: when i am using horizontal UIStackView it''s show randomly displayed in view? How can i do it? Plz help me!

Comment: give the stackview width and height constraints , and from attributes inspector set distribution to fillEqually

Answer (score 0):

You can add multiple buttons with-in UIStackView, Then set the axis property of UIStackView to horizontal or vertical as per your requirement. To make the Radio button set the image of button & give title, then set the left title inset to make some space between button image & title.

Comment: when i am setting UIStackView to horizontal it''s show randomly displayed in view? How can i do it? Plz help me! plz give me any some example code

Answer (score 0):

**For this Simple thing can't need to use any Third-party Library you can Do it by Using** `UIButton` **Like this.**

```
import UIKit

class RootViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var btnMale: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var btnFemale: UIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

@IBAction func btnTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {

    if sender.currentImage == UIImage(named: "radio_unchecked"){

        sender.setImage(UIImage(named: "radio_checked"), for: .normal)

    }else{

        sender.setImage(UIImage(named: "radio_unchecked"), for: .normal)
    }
}
```

In Storyboard Drag and Drop Two `UIButton` Connect its `IBOutlet` and then Connect with Same Action Outlet to Both Button.

[image]

Add images, and one more thing Button Title set with Adding Before Space Like this.

[image]

Change the Alignment from Storyboard Like this.

[image]

**That's it here is Your Output:**

[image]

Comment: i have number of Radio Buttons (i.e 10 buttons), so that it's take 10 tags? but this code is hard  i need less code for that Output! How to Do it in swift?

Comment: @Manohar Yes you need to gives tags to all button by using same think i manage 15 buttons it's batter way without using any third party library. and use native components as possible avoid third party.