# Radio buttons logic FOR 3 BUTTONS swift

Tags: swift3

I am trying to show 3 radio buttons. If Button 1 was selected remaining 2 should be disabled. If button 2 is selected, button 1 and 3 should be disabled. and last if button 3 is selected 1 and 2 should be disabled. I tried to do in multiple ways.but not succeeded. Here is my code any help is appreciated.

```
@IBAction func button1Clicked(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if button2.isSelected {
        button2.isSelected = false
        button1.isSelected = true
    } else {
        button1.isSelected = true
    }
}

@IBAction func button2Clicked(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if button1.isSelected {
        button1.isSelected = false
        button2.isSelected = true
    } else {
        button2.isSelected = true
    }
}


@IBAction func button3Clicked(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if button3.isSelected {
        button3.isSelected = false
        button2.isSelected = true
        //button1.isSelected = true
    } else {
        button1.isSelected = true
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51632267/10150796

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this way by changing UIImage of button:

```
@IBAction func mr(_ sender: Any) {
    mrOutlet.setImage(UIImage(named: "check"), for: .normal)
    msOutlet.setImage(UIImage(named: "uncheck"), for: .normal)
    mrsOutlet.setImage(UIImage(named: "uncheck"), for: .normal)
    salutation = "Mr."
}

@IBAction func ms(_ sender: Any) {
     msOutlet.setImage(UIImage(named: "check"), for: .normal)
    mrOutlet.setImage(UIImage(named: "uncheck"), for: .normal)
    mrsOutlet.setImage(UIImage(named: "uncheck"), for: .normal)
    salutation = "Ms."
}

@IBAction func mrs(_ sender: Any) {
     mrsOutlet.setImage(UIImage(named: "check"), for: .normal)
    mrOutlet.setImage(UIImage(named: "uncheck"), for: .normal)
    msOutlet.setImage(UIImage(named: "uncheck"), for: .normal)
    salutation = "Mrs."
}
```

Hope this help :)